# createUserWithEmailAndPassword redirect causes an error

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, window.location

I want to redirect a user to a part of my site after signup, not signin
So at the end of the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function I change the window.location and it all works fine, I do get an error since the function was interrupted

How do I avoid this? There's signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult but the Firebase documentation doesn't include email as a provider, only facebook

I can try-catch the error but perhaps there's a more elegant way to tackle this?

```
function handleSignUp() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (email.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter an email address.');
        return;
    }
    if (password.length < 4) {
        alert('Please enter a password.');
        return;
    }
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
            alert('The password is too weak.');
        } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
    });
    window.location = "/add-location";
}
```

// console error

```
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occured.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply redirect after successful sign-up:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(function(user) {
    window.location = "/add-location";
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    ...
  });
```

You were redirecting before the promise resolved, hence the interrupted operation error.

Comment: Thank you! I've actually went ahead for a workaround, I'm sending an e-mail to the user to verify his e-mail and the link is /add-location.. two birds with one stone

But your answer seems very reasonable, thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about redirecting after login callback?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in. So redirect:
     window.location = "/add-location";
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account), after creation, auth status changes to logged in automatically so that will trigger the redirection after getting a  successful login.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How would I restrict this to the first login only though - I don't want to redirect to /add-location on sign-in, but only on sign-up (which would be consequently the first sign-in)

Comment: As far as I know, Google doesn't provide information about login type because different methods can be used to sign-in, despite you are using account creation, so you would need to store in the firebase db maybe a path with that info and inside the event listener check that in case of login and redirect in case of first login detected.

Comment: Thanks, i'll most likely go with this if there isn't a simpler solution - it works fine just this error that I'd like to avoid catching